# BigDecimal only showing 2 dp in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bigdecimal

I'm working on a project where I have a model with a BigDecimal value, I have a form which the BigDecimal is shown in, however for some reason it's being truncated to 2 dp.

So for example I have:

```
f.object.value = BigDecimal.new(0.8769479404141033)
```

but

```
<%= f.text_field(:value) %>
```

renders to a text field with 0.88 as the value, which causes problems because I need the extra precision, how do I stop this from happening?

Comment: How work your `BigDecimal`, can you show?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function round()

```
 0.8769479404141033.round(3)
```

out put will be

```
 0.877
```

See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Float.html#method-i-round.

Comment: I'm not sure you've understood the problem, I don't want the value to be rounded, but rails is doing that itself. It seems to be working the same way as to_s does, so for example `BigDecimal.new(0.8769479404141033).to_s` outputs to 0.88